# Python regex discrepancy between compiled and uncompiled regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to understand what is the difference between using `re.MULTILINE` and not using it in Python.

Specifically, I'm seeing differences between how regexps work when using compiled patterns with flags. In this example, I'm using `"blubber"` as input string and `"^blubber$"` as a pattern to match. This should clearly match.

Trying different combinations I get back `None` in the case when I pass `re.MULTILINE` to a compiled regex object's match method. Why would that be?

A test script:

```
import re
import sys

print(sys.version)

input_string = "blubber"
matching_pattern = "^blubber$"


result_one = re.match(matching_pattern, input_string)
print("re.match:                            %r" % (result_one,))

result_two = re.match(matching_pattern, input_string, re.M)
print("re.match multiline:                  %r" % (result_two,))


compiled_re = re.compile(matching_pattern)
result_three = compiled_re.match(input_string)
print("compiled match:                      %r" % (result_three,))

compiled_re = re.compile(matching_pattern)
result_four = compiled_re.match(input_string, re.M)
print("compiled match multiline:            %r" % (result_four,))


compiled_re = re.compile(matching_pattern, re.M)
result_five = compiled_re.match(input_string)
print("compiled multiline match:            %r" % (result_five,))

compiled_re = re.compile(matching_pattern, re.M)
result_six = compiled_re.match(input_string, re.M)
print("compiled multiline match multiline:  %r" % (result_six,))
```

Example run output:

```
$ python3.8 wat_the_re.py 
3.8.3 (default, May 19 2020, 14:59:28) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
re.match:                            <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='blubber'>
re.match multiline:                  <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='blubber'>
compiled match:                      <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='blubber'>
compiled match multiline:            None
compiled multiline match:            <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='blubber'>
compiled multiline match multiline:  None
```

Answer (score 3):

The second named parameter of `pattern.match()` is *not* flags but the matching position. Since the value of `re.M` is 8, the pattern is matched starting from the ninth position. You should pass the flags by name:

```
result_six = compiled_re.match(input_string, flags=re.M)
```

Moreover, you already compiled the pattern with that flag, there is no need to pass it again.

Comment: You are completely correct, sir.